# How to solve 'Warning 1: Field of width 255 truncated to 254.'

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-3, standalone

I get this warning message `Warning 1: Field Date of width 255 truncated to 254.` when I run this code :

```
# Prepare the environment

import sys
import os
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS", True)
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"]="/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/proj"
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 

sys.path.append('/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins') # Path to the file 'processing' (depending of your QGIS version it could be different)
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

# Run the algorithm

def shp(a,b,c):

    format_tuiles=[c,b,a]

    for px in format_tuiles:
        
        processing.run('native:buffer',{'DISSOLVE':False,'DISTANCE':px*2.5,'END_CAP_STYLE':2,'INPUT':'delimitedtext://file:///Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/data_v9.csv?delimiter=;&decimalPoint=,&crs=epsg:32632&xField=UTM32_E&yField=UTM32_N','JOIN_STYLE':1,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/shapefiles_windows/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.shp','SEGMENTS':1})
        print(str(px)+'px')

shp(1,3,11)

# Exit applications

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

This is my CSV input :

```
Date;Name;UTM32_E;UTM32_N
Permanent;NY-A_nmi;562834,932;8762874,054
Permanent;BAYE_awi;560758,523;8762624,904
23/11/2021;Gruv1;562161,731;8762241,255
30/11/2021;Gruv2;562163,570;8762230,172
07/12/2021;Gruv3;562157,970;8762213,131
14/12/2021;Gruv4;562159,817;8762197,578
21/12/2021;Gruv5;562155,545;8762188,425
28/12/2021;Gruv6;562161,409;8762174,189
04/01/2022;Gruv7;562166,361;8762161,025
12/01/2022;Gruv8;562181,144;8762166,229
18/01/2022;Gruv9;562177,375;8762177,217
26/01/2022;Gruv10;562173,731;8762177,036
02/02/2022;Gruv11;562173,425;8762200,489
08/02/2022;Gruv12;562171,966;8762208,239
15/02/2022;Gruv13;562172,912;8762219,461
01/03/2022;Gruv14;562171,487;8762239,505
08/03/2022;Gruv15;562189,976;8762239,306
15/03/2022;Gruv16;562178,630;8762229,802
22/03/2022;Gruv17;562182,828;8762218,836
29/03/2022;Gruv18;562181,563;8762205,363
30/11/2021;Ed1;562426,884;8762775,218
09/12/2021;Ed2;562431,250;8762760,909
21/12/2021;Ed3;562494,361;8762757,355
04/01/2022;Ed4;562496,457;8762754,107
13/01/2022;Ed5;562497,155;8762753,024
27/01/2022;Ed6;562493,213;8762741,652
04/02/2022;Ed7;562485,833;8762734,579
15/02/2022;Ed8;562494,404;8762735,007
01/03/2022;Ed9;562492,048;8762790,765
08/03/2022;Ed10;562495,882;8762718,318
21/03/2022;Ed11;562508,446;8762759,176
31/03/2022;Ed12;562505,425;8762742,263
19/11/2021;Bay1;560766,614;8762621,944
09/12/2021;Bay2;560769,776;8762618,746
21/12/2021;Bay3;560766,990;8762618,610
13/01/2022;Bay4;560771,007;8762619,923
04/02/2022;Bay5;560771,759;8762617,725
15/02/2022;Bay6;560765,121;8762608,463
01/03/2022;Bay7;560772,298;8762611,046
08/03/2022;Bay8;560772,194;8762604,336
21/03/2022;Bay9;560772,408;8762643,580
31/03/2022;Bay10;560779,268;8762600,210
```

Just in case that is my terminal :

```
pugliesipc@Pierres-MacBook-Air ~ % /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/python3.8 /Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/Phase_2/python/test.py
Warning 1: Field Date of width 255 truncated to 254.
Warning 1: Field Name of width 255 truncated to 254.
11px
Warning 1: Field Date of width 255 truncated to 254.
Warning 1: Field Name of width 255 truncated to 254.
3px
Warning 1: Field Date of width 255 truncated to 254.
Warning 1: Field Name of width 255 truncated to 254.
1px
pugliesipc@Pierres-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

I do not understand what width is `255` and what is it doing when it tell me `truncated to 254`.

Comment: I do not know how to solve the issue, but I believe I know what is the reason. GDAL is probably using a default width of 255 characters with string fields of CSV data even that is not documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html. However, shapefile format that you use for output supports only 254 characters https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm. Possible fix could be to write a csvt file and define a smaller width for the date and name fields. Or just write the result into GeoPackage instead of shape.

Comment: I see what you mean, I will try your suggestion ! But I am wondering why I do not get this same warning for the other filed ?

Comment: The maximum field width of a dBase file is 254. dBase supports a true date field type, though it is restricted to just day resolution.

Comment: I understand that the character limit is 255 for csv and 254 for shapefile. So as long as I export csv to shp it will be truncated. But what I don’t understand is why I get this warning message only for Name et Date field?

Comment: It is probably because the process is different between string and number

Comment: What surprises me is that I am far from 255 character, so what is width ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user30184 suggested using .gpkg instead of .shp do the tricks

> Or just write the result into GeoPackage instead of shape.

**UPDATE**

I am not sure I found a solution but at least I found a trick. By using the tool `refactorfields` we can edit the length of the fields link to the warning.

In my case `Field Date` and `Field Name` length were `0` and I change it for `10`.

Then, what was :

```
processing.run('native:buffer',{'DISSOLVE':False,'DISTANCE':px*2.5,'END_CAP_STYLE':2,'INPUT':'delimitedtext://file:///Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/data_v9.csv?delimiter=;&decimalPoint=,&crs=epsg:32632&xField=UTM32_E&yField=UTM32_N','JOIN_STYLE':1,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/shapefiles_windows/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.shp','SEGMENTS':1})
```

Is now :

```
processing.run('native:refactorfields',{ 'FIELDS_MAPPING' : [{'expression': '"Date"','length': 10,'name': 'Date','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Name"','length': 10,'name': 'Name','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"UTM32_E"','length': 0,'name': 'UTM32_E','precision': 0,'type': 6},{'expression': '"UTM32_N"','length': 0,'name': 'UTM32_N','precision': 0,'type': 6}], 'INPUT' : 'delimitedtext://file:///Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/data_v9.csv?type=regexp&delimiter=;&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&decimalPoint=,&xField=UTM32_E&yField=UTM32_N&crs=EPSG:32632&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'OUTPUT' : '/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/shp/data_v9.shp' })
processing.run('native:buffer',{'DISSOLVE':False,'DISTANCE':2.5,'END_CAP_STYLE':2,'INPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/shp/data_v9.shp','JOIN_STYLE':1,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/shapefiles_windows/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.shp','SEGMENTS':1})
```

Finally, just in case you were wondering this is not solving the issue :

```
processing.run('native:savefeatures',{ 'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS' : '', 'INPUT' : 'delimitedtext://file:///Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/data_v9.csv?type=regexp&delimiter=;&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&decimalPoint=,&xField=UTM32_E&yField=UTM32_N&crs=EPSG:32632&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'LAYER_NAME' : '', 'LAYER_OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : '/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/shp/data_v9.shp' })
processing.run('native:buffer',{'DISSOLVE':False,'DISTANCE':2.5,'END_CAP_STYLE':2,'INPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/shp/data_v9.shp','JOIN_STYLE':1,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/shapefiles_windows/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.shp','SEGMENTS':1})
```