# Solve "ERROR: Too many connections: max 64 while"

Tags: python, qgis-3, qgis-processing, standalone

I would like to apply `zonalstatisticsfb` to 30 raster file on 3 different areas each time. I guess Python have to loop 90 times.

This is the code I am using :

```
def extract_stats(a,b,c):

    import pandas as pd # Ce module facilite l'exploitation des fichiers CSV

    format_tuiles=[a,b,c]
    output=[pd.DataFrame()]*3
    radar_image='/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/TSX/CCOH_21_22'

    list_radar_image=os.listdir(radar_image)

    for file in list_radar_image:

        i=0
        date=file[14:16]+'/'+file[12:14]+'/'+file[8:12]
        path_to_radar_output=radar_image+'/'+file
        print(date)

        for px in format_tuiles:
            processing.run('native:zonalstatisticsfb',{'COLUMN_PREFIX':'_','INPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/shapefiles_windows/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.gpkg','INPUT_RASTER':path_to_radar_output,'OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Shapefile_stat/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.gpkg','RASTER_BAND':1,'STATISTICS':[2]})
            processing.run('native:savefeatures',{'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'','INPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Shapefile_stat/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.gpkg','LAYER_NAME':'','LAYER_OPTIONS':'','OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Sortie_txt/CCOH_21_22/output'+str(px)+'.csv'})
            temporary_csv=pd.read_csv('/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Sortie_txt/CCOH_21_22/output'+str(px)+'.csv')
            output[i]=pd.concat([output[i],temporary_csv,pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'Date':'#','Name':'#','UTM32_E':'#','UTM32_N':'#','_mean':'#'}])])
            i+=1
            
    i=0

    for px in format_tuiles: 
        output[i].to_csv('/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Sortie_txt/CCOH_21_22/output_'+str(px)+'px.csv')
        i+=1

extract_stats(1,3,11)
```

This is the error I get after some iteration :

> ERROR: Too many connections: max 64

Maybe I should close something at the end of each iteration ?

Answer (score 0):

This my script :

```
# Prepare the environment

import sys
import os # Ce module permet d'utiliser les fonctionnalités du système d'exploitation
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS", True)
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"]="/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/proj"
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 

sys.path.append('/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins') # Folder where Processing is located
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

# Run the algorithm

def windows(a,b,c):

    format_tuiles=[a,b,c] # Dans l'ordre décroissant pour une bonne superposition des couches

    for px in format_tuiles:
        
        processing.run('native:refactorfields',{'FIELDS_MAPPING':[{'expression':'"Date"','length':1,'name':'Date','precision':0,'type':10},{'expression':'"Name"','length':1,'name':'Name','precision':0,'type':10}],'INPUT':'delimitedtext://file:///Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/data_v9.csv?type=regexp&delimiter=;&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&decimalPoint=,&xField=UTM32_E&yField=UTM32_N&crs=EPSG:32632&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no','OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/shp/data_v9.shp'})
        processing.run('native:buffer',{'DISSOLVE':False,'DISTANCE':2.5,'END_CAP_STYLE':2,'INPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/data/shp/data_v9.shp','JOIN_STYLE':1,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/shapefiles_windows/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.shp','SEGMENTS':1})
        print(str(px)+'px windows was created')

windows(1,3,11)

def extract_stats(a,b,c,parameter):

    import pandas as pd # Ce module facilite l'exploitation des fichiers CSV

    format_tuiles=[a,b,c]
    output=[pd.DataFrame()]*3
    radar_image='/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/TSX/'+parameter+'_21_22'

    print('Extracting statistics from '+radar_image+'...')

    list_radar_image=os.listdir(radar_image)

    for file in list_radar_image:

        i=0
        date=file[14:16]+'/'+file[12:14]+'/'+file[8:12]
        path_to_radar_output=radar_image+'/'+file

        for px in format_tuiles:
            processing.run('native:zonalstatisticsfb',{'COLUMN_PREFIX':'_','INPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/shapefiles_windows/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.shp','INPUT_RASTER':path_to_radar_output,'OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Shapefile_stat/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.shp','RASTER_BAND':1,'STATISTICS':[2,4]})
            processing.run('native:savefeatures',{'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'','INPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Shapefile_stat/'+str(px)+'px/'+str(px)+'px.shp','LAYER_NAME':'','LAYER_OPTIONS':'','OUTPUT':'/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Sortie_txt/'+parameter+'_21_22/output_'+str(px)+'px.csv'})
            temporary_csv=pd.read_csv('/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Sortie_txt/'+parameter+'_21_22/output_'+str(px)+'px.csv')
            output[i]=pd.concat([output[i],temporary_csv,pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'Date':'#','Name':'#','UTM32_E':'#','UTM32_N':'#','_mean':'#','_stdev':'#'}])])
            i+=1
            
    i=0

    for px in format_tuiles: 
        output[i].to_csv('/Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_windows/Sortie_txt/'+parameter+'_21_22/output_'+str(px)+'px.csv')
        i+=1

extract_stats(1,3,11,'CCOH')
extract_stats(1,3,11,'CPD')

# Exit applications

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

The first function gave me warnings while converting .csv to .shp, that is why I decide to use .gpkg rather than .shp (see this [topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428673/how-to-solve-warning-1-field-of-width-255-truncated-to-254)). Moreover .gpkg is more convenient because it is just one file.

Then the second function of my script gave me error as it is described above. This error occur only while I am using .gpkg. Because I do not success to handle with it I decided to go back and re-use .shp instead of .gpkg. I finally found a solution to make the warnings go away. It is described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428673/how-to-solve-warning-1-field-of-width-255-truncated-to-254).